# Coding JavaScript in the conditional issue

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I know that this is basic JavaScript: when I open it in HTML it asks me the question but then doesn't follow through with the next line of code when I have answered the question. I don't now why this is and I would really appreciate some help.

```
<html>
<head>hi</head>
<script>if ( confirm("do you want to do the quiz") === true ) {
console.log("good")
}
else
{
console.log("ok")
 }
if ( prompt("What is the capital of france?") === "Paris" ) {
Console.log("that is right")
}
else
{
consle.log("unlucky")
}


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You misspelled `console` twice. It's lower-case 'c'.

Comment: Also keep your browser developer tools open. You would have seen an error message.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly, really appreciate it. I'm coding in Notepad as part of html so no error message comes up. I corrected the typos but still the 'good', 'ok', and 'unlucky' still don't some up. I was wondering if adding a delay before the next command may help but I don't know how to do that. Would really appreciate some more help. Many thanks. Luke.

Comment: You have to run this in a web browser, and in order to see the output from `console.log()` you have to have the browser developer tools open.

Comment: Thanks working fine now. Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled console and also JavaScript is a case-sensitive language so console cannot be written as Console

try this

```js
if ( confirm("do you want to do the quiz") === true ) {
console.log("good")
}
else
{
console.log("ok")
 }
if ( prompt("What is the capital of france?") === "Paris" ) {
console.log("that is right")
}
else
{
console.log("unlucky")
}
```

Comment: I ran your code but it still doesn't say the 'good' bit or 'ok'. Would appreciate some more help. Thanks. Luke

Comment: Please use developer tools (google chrome press f12) and in developer tools open console.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this , You have misspell `console.log` in two place

```
<html>
<head>hi</head>
<script>if ( confirm("do you want to do the quiz") === true ) {
console.log("good")
}
else
{
console.log("ok")
 }
if ( prompt("What is the capital of france?") === "Paris" ) {
console.log("that is right")
}
else
{
console.log("unlucky")
}


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the quick reply but it still doesn't say 'good' 'ok' or 'unlucky'. Thanks. Luke.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking user if he wants to play quiz, and if the user selects ok then you continue the quiz. For this you need to add all your quiz part in if block with console.log("good");

```
if(confirm("wanna play quiz?")){
   // start quiz
   if(prompt("question")=="answer"){
      console.log("That's right")
   }
   // more questions...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the quick reply but the line under the 'if' line doesn't come up it just moves straigght on to the nextquestion. Thanks. Luke